# How to use pivot_longer properly in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, data-manipulation

I'm currently working on a simple `pivot_longer` function in [r](/questions/tagged/r).

Here is the code:

```
poll %>%
  pivot_longer(poll, c(`Basketball`,`Football`),
   names_to="Sport", 
   values_to="Percentage")
```

Theses are codes to find the percentage of basketball and football.

Here is the error message:

> Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.

Can anyone please see what is wrong with my code?

Comment: can you dput(poll) or dput(head(poll,10)), and paste the output? this way we can see what is the data.frame

Answer (score 0):

```
poll %>% 
   pivot_longer(c("Basketball","Football"), names_to="Sport", values_to="Percentage")
```

OR

```
pivot_longer(poll, c("Basketball","Football"), names_to="Sport", values_to="Percentage")
```